# Get a process window size without borders

Tags: c#, winapi

Using the WinApi GetWindowRect() it returns the complete window size, but I would like to get the size without the borders and the title bar, something like the red square:

[image]

There is any functions to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows API function you are looking for is [`GetClientRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503.aspx). If you subsequently need to convert these coordinates into screen relative coordinates, call [`ClientToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183434.aspx).

Comment: I tried to call ClientToScreen, but it returns a Point, I need to get the Rect values, so I can see what coordinates it start at top/bottom/right/left, the GetClientRect returns only the Height/Width and not really a Rect

Comment: A rect is defined to two points. Top-left and bottom-right. For a client rect the top-left is always (0,0). Call `ClientToScreen` twice, once each for the two points that define the rect and you now have the two points that define the rect in screen coords.

Comment: So basically I have to calculate the values and set a Rect for use? The ClientToScreen is returning a crazy value, like X=1.18831764296032E-312 and Y=0, the window Handle is correct since it's been used in other function that works good, should I do something different to get that point using the ClientToScreen?

Comment: Your code is clearly wrong. Coordinates are integers. There should be no floating point values here.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I had created a Windows.Point and not a Drawing.Point. Anyway, it returns the top-left corner, but how can I get the bottom-right? Calling ClientToScreen twice will just increase my point value by 2x